# How to create MultipartFile with location file (path)

Tags: java

I have location file (C:\fakepath\Code.txt) . I want to create MultipartFile with this location. My Code:

```
public void fileUpload(String locationFile) {

    Path path = Paths.get(locationFile);
    String name = "Code.txt";
    String originalFileName = "Code.txt";
    String contentType = "text/plain";
    byte[] content = null;
    try {
        content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
    }
    MultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile(name, originalFileName, contentType, content);

    try {
        // Get the file and save it somewhere
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        Path paths = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(paths, bytes);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Also in this code I need type my file name it's not correct for my opinion. How to create MultipartFile and save somewhere? with location

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you need double slashes "C://fakepath//Code.txt"